# Select returns no rows - queries in trace file

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms, sql-server-profiler

I [imported a trace](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/270599) file using

```
SELECT * INTO trace_table FROM ::fn_trace_gettable('c:\my_trace.trc', default)
```

While [analyzing my imported trace file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40527667/) i noticed that certain select statements take a significant amount of time (duration) and cpu but at the end do not return any rows (`RowsCount == NULL`).

```
SELECT TextData, ClientProcessID, EventClass
        , Duration, StartTime, EndTime
        , Reads, Writes, CPU, RowCounts
        , EventSequence,  TextData_md5_hash    
        , ApplicationName, SPID
FROM MyImportedTrace
WHERE 
      TextData_md5_hash in (0x4A943F266010BDD2A47179DC3481BC7F)
ORDER BY SPID, StartTime, EventSequence
```

Example

[image: slow select without any rows]

#### Test in query window

If i copy the same query from the  `TextData`-Field into a query window i get a lot of rows (>200000)

### Questions

- What might be a reason that the query did not return any rows?
- Was the query terminated ?
- How do i recognize failed query executions in a trace file?

#### Update / Edit after Answer accepted

This query

```
Use MyDatabase
SELECT ti.EventClass, te.Eventname, Count(*) as CountAsterisk
    , Sum(ti.RowCounts) as RowCountsSum
    , Sum(ti.Duration/1000) as DurationSum_ms
    , Avg(ti.Duration/1000) as DurationAvg_ms
FROM TraceImport ti
    Left JOIN TraceEvents te  
         ON ti.EventClass = te.EventTraceID
Group By ti.EventClass, te.Eventname 
Order By EventClass
```

Returns this result

[image: Group Trace Rows by Event Class]

Comment: Are you checking if it contains data by doing the `rowscount==null` or displaying data? Because I believe it is `@@rowcount`

Comment: RowCounts of null means that you aren't collecting it. Not that it is 0.

Comment: You are correct, that `@@rowcount` can be used to query the returned rows. In my case the imported trace file contains a column `RowsCount`. An this column usual has a value > 0 (and `NOT NULL`) for a select statement.  Executing the query from the field `TextData` in MMS returns rows. But during our user-performance-test the same statement it seems that it did not return any rows (hence `NULL` in the imported trace file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sys.fn_trace_gettable` returns every possible column that might have been captured.

There is no guarantee that the actual trace you are looking at did capture `RowCounts` for every relevant event class.

Based on the information you have provided so far there is no reason to think that the trace wasn't set up like this.

Inside [ssms](/questions/tagged/ssms) click on `Tools / SQL Server Profiler` that opens the [sql-server-profiler](/questions/tagged/sql-server-profiler) application in the window `Trace properties` click on the tab `Event selection` and make sure that the column `RowCounts` is checked for the event class `SQL:BatchCompleted`

[image: SQL Server profiler / Trace properties / Event selection]

Comment: Some rows in the imported trace-file have a value `>0` in the column `RowCounts`. So i would assume that every row that contains a Select that returns rows should have `RowCounts >0`.

Comment: @surfmuggle what event class do they have?

Comment: The rows in question have event class  12 and 13. Regarding the [function `sys.fn_trace_gettable('filename', number_files)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188425.aspx) this is how i imported the trace-file.  It seems that [sp_trace_setevent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx) is only available from sql-server 2012 onwards

Comment: @surfmuggle - that can't be correct. 13 is batch starting. It can't have a row count. What does `SELECT  COUNT(*), EventClass
FROM MyImportedTrace
WHERE RowCounts > 0
GROUP BY EventClass` return?

Comment: The query returned `616 rows for event class 43` and `10968 rows for event class 45`.  I filtered the trace using `TextData like 'SELECT%MyTable%'` for the given MD5-hash `0x4A943F266...BC7F` this returned only two rows with event class `12 = SQL:BatchCompleted` and `13= SQL:BatchStarting`. Could it be that the query was aborted for some reason (timeout)?

Comment: @surfmuggle - No it means you aren't capturing that column for event class 12. 43 and 45 are `SP:Completed`, `SP:StmtCompleted` 12 is `SQL:BatchCompleted`

Comment: Thanks i did not know that this has to be configured for every event class. Reading up on [`SQL:BatchCompleted`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176010.aspx) and [`sp_trace_setevent`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186265.aspx) did not help. But with your screenshot know this makes things clear.